# Ser no Incremental problem in VB Visual Studio 2019,

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXkQL.jpg)
See the ser no increment at the bottom right hand corner with text ser no. which is supposed to be matching with the Navigation tool strip no. it is happening after a break of 2-3 hours when i open the laptop and start to insert new data. I tried many ways no joy. any one can halp me solve this problem.

Comment: @GSerg I noticed this and it has been bothering me for months. I didn't know quite what to search for. Thank you for this info.

Comment: So what was the remedy? You didn't mention any thing. It was in VB.net